# How can I make my header position correctly across mobile and desktop devices?

Tags: html, css

Alright, I am not a CSS expert, and most of the time work in back end web development, but I am having some difficulty with making my header "just look right" on mobile and desktop.

Up until now, I was a avoiding the problem by just making a mobile site. This turned out to be a huge hassle, because managing and testing features on two sites is more work then necessary. Also mobile sites are becoming phased out as more and more developers design sites to support al screen sizes.

I have the following layout as my header:
[image]

This is my ideal layout; how I would like it to look. Though it took some dirty CSS hacks to get it here.

Now the main problem is how this adjust on mobile, which looks like this:
[image]

So to start off this is my HTML in my  tag.

```
<div id="header">

<a href="index.html"><h1>FlareHub</h1></a>

<ul>
  <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>News</a></li>
  <li><a href="vipinfo.html"><i class="fa fa-star"></i>VIP</a></li>
  <li><a href="games.html"><i class="fa fa-trophy"></i>Games</a></li>
  <li><a href="vote.html"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i>Vote</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>Account</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="loginwebsite.php"><i class="fa fa-key"></i>Login</a>
    <a href="signup.php"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>Signup</a>
    <a href="help.html"><i class="fa fa-life-ring"></i>Help & Support</a>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
</head>
```

Lets now take a look at the CSS. Most of the hacks here are to correctly position the Account menu dropdown.

```
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline:none;
    margin-top: -14.7px;
    font-family: "smooth";
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    margin-top: -23.5px;
    margin-left: 75%;

}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: transparent;
}
/*Header Text*/
#header h1 {
    font-family: "smooth";
    font-size: 45px;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    height: 0;
}

/* Make unordered list horizontle */
#header ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: -12.5px;
    margin-left: 270px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: none;
}

/* Make unordered list horizontle */
#header ul li {
    display: inline;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: none;
}

/* Make boxed & colored */
#header ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: .2% 3%;
    color: #FFF; /*Text color, when not hovered*/
}

/* Make change colors, when hovered on */
#header ul li a:hover{
    color: lightgray; /*Text color*/
}

/* Header box */
#header{
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #3385ff;
    margin-top: -9px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: auto;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

/*Remove line*/
#header a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Header navigation font */
#header li{
    font-family: "smooth";
}
```

Some hacks like `margin-top: -14.7px;`, are to keep the account element linear with the list. I really hate hardcoding values like this, and would love to find alternatives to remove `margin-top: -23.5px;`, `margin-left: 75%;`, etc.

How can I fix up my CSS/HTML to make everything position correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `media queries` in order for you to set the right CSS for situational screen size.

Example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}
```

body will change color only once the screen size is met by the media query. Thus, it will be the same thing with your positioning. Read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Answer (score 0):

You use media queries in your css. e.a.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
}
```

This way you can pretty much write overuling rules for every size or device.

You can read about them here:

[Css media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp)

Answer (score 0):

if it's not important , maybe you  can hide it